# OCR reader for xamarin code? i can use web API as well please suggest any?

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin for development as new way to develop iOS apps, i want to get OCR for Xamarin tool for iOS...

Please help to solve this?

Thanks Again..

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's a github project which uses mentioned tesseract-ios as a binding project. Just checkout and run. I can confirm that Unified API (Xamarin iOS 8.6.0) works like a charm :)

https://github.com/sraiteri/Xamarin-Tesseract-OCR-iOS

The only thing I've found tricky is adding custom language to the engine. I'll edit this post when I'll come up with a solution

Answer (score 1):

You could write  binding for the Tesseract project:

https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios

Comment: Thats why you need to write a binding. you can use any native ios library in xamarin, that is the beauty of it. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Xamarin but if you'r looking for a great OCR API, I suggest you to look into Abby. I've used them on a project a few years ago and it was really good.

http://www.abbyy.com/promo/ocr_sdk/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you suggest any other for Xamarin?